# How can I tell what will actually be displayed in game?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having a serious issue with Unity. It's most definitely a conceptual issue, and I would love some help understanding what I'm doing wrong.

The game window on the Unity editor shows my game working exactly as intended. The sizing of everything is perfect, the animations fit nicely, and everything is how I want it to be.

The problem, however, is that when I actually build the game, nothing is where it should be. The animations are off. The sizing of buttons and canvas UI elements are wonky. This is not what I see represented in the Unity editor, so I have no idea why it's working like that.

I've tried changing canvas to scale with screen size because the canvas elements are what is bugging.

I expect my built game to look exactly as it does in the unity editor, but that's not happening.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your Game tab in the editor set to specific resolution (and not on free aspect)? And do you fully understand how a RectTransform is set-up?

Comment: My game tab is set to free aspect. These buttons have a slide in animation so I'm not sure how that works with rect transform.

Comment: Set the game tab to your target resolution and you will see how it will look for it. Then read/watch YT multiple different explanations how RectTransform works. It's counter-intuitive at the beginning but at some point will click and will make perfect sense.

Comment: Alright, will do - but what if the user's screen is too wide? what will they see? obviously it won't stretch, so will it just be black / blue?

Comment: Everyone will see according to his resolution. UI will move around according to RectTransform setup.